# React Router 4 - Route to a default component if a broken link has entered

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-v4

I am working on React Router 4. I have some components like `home, page1.., and page404`. I want to redirect to the `page404` if a broken link has entered.

```
            <Router>
                <AppContainer>
                    <Route exact path={HOME_URL} component={Home}/>
                    <Route path={SEARCH_RESULTS_URL} component={SearchResults}/>
                    <Route path={PAGE_404} component={Page404}/>
                </AppContainer>
            </Router>
```

Can anyone please suggest a method.

Comment: what is your definition of broken link and what is the path for PAGE_404

Comment: In the sense, if I type something on URL and press enter. If it doesn't match with HOME_URL, SEARCH_RESULTS_URL. Then it should redirect to PAGE_404

Comment: @Nicholas answer should help you in that case

Comment: But with @Nicholas solution, There is `<p> 404 Page </p>` always after every main container.

Comment: Make sure you are using Switch from react-router to wrap your routes https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    const routes = (
     <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/home" component={Home/>
        <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound}/>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
   );
```

Answer (score 2):

The docs seem to indicate that you have to wrap this in a `<Switch>`:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path={HOME_URL} component={Home}/>
    <Route path={SEARCH_RESULTS_URL} component={SearchResults}/>
    <Route component={PAGE_404}/>
</Switch>
```

Comment: This works fine now. But what my requirement is to redirect to page404 if the link is broken.

Comment: Not sure I understand your definition of broken link?

Answer (score 1):

The switch works like this, you give it to the end a route with a render component, in my case I just returned a paragraph. So if user goes to an URL other than what you defined 404 page will return

```
 <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
            <Route exact path='/about' component={About}/>
            <Route path='/about/results' component={Results}/>
            <Route path='/popular' component={Popular}/>
            <Route render={function () {
              return <p> 404 Page </p>
            }} />
          </Switch>
      </Router>
```

Comment: The `<p> 404 Page </p>` is always showing after the main container.

Answer (score 0):

Catch the route if it doesn't matches any with this path at the last :

```
<Route component={page404} />
```